# Can we give a categorical definition of product without using any sub/superscripts or cheating?

Tags: category-theory, products, categorical-logic

For instance changing notation from $C_i$ to $C(i)$ would be considered cheating unless $C$ is a functor from a category $I$.

I'm trying to figure out a way to simplify handling category constructs in code.  If there were a way to remove sub/superscripting, that would be awesome.

For instance "consider the family of objects in $\mathcal{C}$, $\{C_i\}_{i \in I}$ ..." Then can't we do something like have $I$ be a discrete category and have $C: I \to \mathcal{C}$ be a functor.  Then how would we go about handling a family of maps $C_i \xrightarrow{s_i} P$ (in the usual definition of coproduct e.g.)  Would we just consider a functor from $I$ into $\text{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$?  or $P\setminus \mathcal{C}$ the coslice category?

I'm trying to think of creative ways to handle human conventions in math, such as subscripting.  We take such things for granted because they come natural to us.  But on a computer, if I let one thing happen such as subscripting, then I open the door to a whole slew of a mess.  So since we are talking about category theory here, there has got to be some tricks to make alternative definitions.

I hope that makes sense now.

Comment: This is exactly what one does when considering limits/colimits of which products/coproducts are special cases.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown but all definitions of limits I've seen use subscripts! lol

Comment: I don't understand in what way considering subscripts is worse than considering functors from discrete categories. That's just what subscripts are.

Comment: Because subscripts can get really complicated once the theory picks up speed.  And also, I'd like a way to say $\forall i \in I$ diagramatically.  My app will only have English / math prose if I can convert these diagrams into that, and not the other way around.  Just as code generation is way easier to me than code parsing.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan can you show me a subscriptless definition of product that is purely diagramatical?  By that I mean, a diagram is a blank space on my app that is filled with object nodes and morphism arrows.  Those are all assumed to be in the category, and when you draw a dotted arrow, that means a consequential existence is asserted true.  In other words, I'm trying to be 90% visual and 10% textual.

Comment: I'm not claiming that subscripts are good, I just don't understand how considering a functor from $I$ to $C$ is less bad than subscripts. You want to draw a diagram in $C$, but if you just draw an arrow from $I$ to $C$ you're drawing a diagram in $\text{Cat}$, not in $C$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan it is less bad because I don't have to parse subscripts for one, or interpret their meaning.  If I can generalize the concept using something I must have: functors, that would be better than coding for both concepts.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yes, true.  I'm still figuring out a good design of the app.  Because you're right, how do I present multiple categories etc.

Comment: @EnjoysMath I don't recommend accepting answers that quickly. At this point 11 people have seen the question and probably not that much more have had the opportunity to.

Comment: @DerekElkins I can re-select a better answer, I'm always on here.

Comment: @EnjoysMath The point is that people will usually not write new answers to questions that already have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way of defining a (co)limit is via $\mathsf{Nat}(\Delta X,D)\cong\mathsf{Hom}(X, \mathsf{Lim}D)$ natural in $X$ and also $D : \mathcal{I}\to\mathcal{C}$ if you have all limits of shape $\mathcal{I}$. $\Delta : \mathcal{C}\to[\mathcal{I},\mathcal{C}]$ is the constant functor, i.e. the exponential transpose of $\pi_1$ in $\mathbf{Cat}$ and $\mathcal{I}$ is assumed to be small. For products, you can just take the discrete category. Colimits look like $\mathsf{Hom}(\mathsf{Colim}D,X)\cong\mathsf{Nat}(D,\Delta X)$. If you have all limits/colimits of shape $\mathcal{I}$, then you can also express these as $\mathsf{Colim}\dashv \Delta\dashv \mathsf{Lim}$.

You may want to look at Cáccamo's and Winskel's [A Higher Order Calculus for Categories](http://www.brics.dk/RS/01/27/index.html) and Hagino's thesis, [A Categorical Programming Language](http://web.sfc.keio.ac.jp/~hagino/thesis.pdf). I don't really think avoiding subscripts is a good idea, though I thoroughly appreciate the complexities of adding binding forms to a language.

Answer (score 3):

You can say that a category has all $I$-ary products if the diagonal functor $C \to C^I$ given by sending an object $c$ to the constant $I$-shaped diagram with value $c$ has a right adjoint. This adjunction can in turn be expressed using [unit-counit adjunctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors#Counit%E2%80%93unit_adjunction), which are purely diagrammatic, although the diagrams are 2-categorical rather than categorical. (For a sample of what "globular" 2-categorical diagrams look like see [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/centers-2-categories-and-the-eckmann-hilton-argument/).) The same is true replacing $I$ with a category and so considering $I$-shaped limits. Is this the sort of thing you want?

Comment: If the notation $C^I$ counts as a superscript, uh, replace it with $[I, C]$. There. I got rid of it.

Comment: You're right, I do need some sub/super scripting but not a lot of it!